# Apply filter to 2nd dashboard without immediately jumping to 2nd dashboard in Tableau?

Tags: filter, tableau-api, dashboard

I am having a problem with applying a filter without instantly moving to the dashboard I want the filter to be on.

Here is the situation. I have Dash A that holds some info and a bar chart. This bar chart is colored based on the system names in the data. Lets call them System One, Two and Three.

I have a 2nd dashboard called Dash B. The goal is to select one of the colors in the bar chart on Dash A and to stay on Dash A until the user presses a button on the dash that then takes them to Dash B where the data will be filtered by whatever system color was selected in Dash A.

Currently when applying a filter either it jumps directly to Dash B or I can use a menu option to allow the user to select a link after clicking a color to then move to the dash board however I don't wont either options.

> Is there a way to apply a filter to a 2nd dashboard from the 1st dashboard without switching dashboards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to filter from one worksheet/dashboard to another worksheet/dashboard without it going to it using the

> Add Filter Action

[image]

Comment: The filter action moves me to the next dashboard. That is the entire problem. This was the 1st thing I tried.

Comment: Please try dashboard to worksheet filter. It will filter the worksheet when you use the dashboard. Since you will add the worksheet on dashboard 2, it should filter. Pls let me know. Updated pic

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have a few things I needed to work on before I get back to the Tableau project. This worked as needed. Its a bit of work as I have to set a filter for every single worksheet on the 2nd dashboard but it does do exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Run Action on 'Menu' to go to Dash B 
Additionally, add a 'Select' filter only targeting Dash A.

Comment: I already mentioned the menu option in my post and not wanting to use that.